# Does a drakewardens companion keep attacking the same creature or must it be told to do so every round?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, action-economy

I have been reading *Fizban's Treasury of Dragons* and playing Drakewarden. I noticed the wording of the Drake Companion:

> It can move and use its reaction on its own, but the only action it takes on its turn is the Dodge action, unless you take a bonus action on your turn to command it to take another action. That action can be one in its stat block or some other action.

Surely if you told the creature in round 1 "Kill these 3 goblins" - you wouldn't have to use your bonus action every round to say "Keep doing that" right, or am I just interpreting this wrong?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I suspect the downvotes are from the tone of your question, which seems biased towards confirmation of your proposal that you could get around the rules as written to get an advantage. It might work better if presented as a neutral question, instead.

Comment: I don't think the question is overly biased. There are some controlled creatures that can continue following an order from a previous turn (off the top of my head, those created by *Animate Objects* for example), so it's a reasonable question whether a drakewarden's companion is one of them. Sure, the wording could be more neutral, but it's a legitimate question.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Yes I agree, I just was commenting on a possible reason for the downvotes.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin - This aint reddit - im not here for the upvotes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### You must spend a bonus action each time.

You have to spend a bonus action to command the creature, but this command is limited to the standard actions and actions from the drake's stat block. "Kill these 3 goblins" is not an action the drake can take.

Since the actions the drake can take are all single use you have to spend a bonus action each turn to make it do anything else than take the dodge action. This is part of the balancing of the action economy of the feature.

Comment: It might help to contrast this with [Animate Dead](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-dead), which has much broader wording, and allows more general, ongoing commands.

Comment: ...it might be good if you pointed out the obvious too which is in the quote in the question itself:

"the ONLY action it takes on its turn is the Dodge action, UNLESS you take a bonus action on your turn to command it"

Comment: The text very clearly says that the command is NOT limited to an action from the drake's stat block. It says: " That action can be one in its stat block or some other action.". However, I do agree that you must spend a bonus action each time and I wouldn't consider "Kill those three goblins" to be "some other action".